# RBAC для различных моделей пользователей

Tags: база-данных, алгоритм, asp.net

Возник вопрос проектирования распределения ролей пользователей имеющих свои различные данные. Приведу пример не касающийся моего, но более простой.

Есть такие модели: `Декан`, `Преподаватель`, `Студент`, `Абитуриент`. У этих моделей есть свои характеристики (свойства):

- Декан - заведует факультетом, срок работы и т.д.
- Преподаватель - предметная специализация, квалификация и т.д.
- Студент - группа, средний балл и т.д.
- Абитуриент - заявки на поступление и т.д.

А также будет две модели для системы аутентификации `Пользователь`, `Роль` и, возможно, `права доступа` (но пока они не нужны)

- Пользователь - данные для входа (логин и пароль), токен для Auth2.0,
  Роль и т.д.
- Роль - название роли, права доступа и т.д.

```cs
public class Dean
{
    public string Faculty { get; set; }
    public int Experience { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Teacher
{
    public string Specialization { get; set; }
    public string Qualification { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Student
{
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public double Average { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Enrollee
{
    public virtual ICollection<Bid> Bids { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class User
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

Согласно паттерну RBAC у нас должны быть субъекты S (User), которые имеют много ролей R (Role), Role имеет много прав доступа P (Permission). Но как же быть с моделями Декан, Преподаватель, Студент, Абитуриент?

На данный момент я вижу пока только такие решения, которые считаю неправильными:

- Назначать для каждой модели поле UserId, связывающее сущность каждого
  пользователя с системой аутентификации (добавить, например, в Dean
  `public int? UserId {get; set;}`).
- Вместо всех моделей, использовать только одну User, со всеми полями
  прошлых моделей (что еще ужаснее)

Как всё таки реализовать подобную систему, чтобы она была маштабируемой, сопровождаемой и главное правильной?